# Regular expression for excluding a duplicate match when it's a substring

Tags: regex

I have a string which looks somewhat like this:

```
style="background-color: red; color: green;"
```

And I used to replace the properties of my (CSS) string with the following regular expression:

```
color: ([a-zA-Z0-9\.]*)
```

[image]

The problem here is, that it would also match on background-color, but I'd like it to match for color only.

(I'm using this to replace the values of the properties)

Comment: So, you want to match color, provided that it's preceded by either `"` or `;` (and, optionally, some whitespace between that preceding character and color). Or do you have more examples (e.g. might `{` also be a valid preceding character)?

Comment: This sounds possible with lookbehinds, if they're available in your regex - what programming language/framework/library are you obtaining your regex implementation from?

Comment: I'm working with TypeScript/JavaScript. And it's supposed to be used like shown above where the style tag is being edited. It actually works but it doesn't work anymore if the two properties start with the same text like in my exaMPle above :/ And sorry by the way, didn't see these comments initially!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?:^|[^\-0-9A-Za-z])color:\s*([a-zA-Z0-9\.]*)
```

- `(?:^|[^\-0-9A-Za-z])` matches either *start of text* or any character but a minus sign, a digit or a letter (these may be part of a CSS property name)
- `color:` matches your CSS property name. Note: consider applying your regex case-insensitively
- `\s*` matches optional space after colon
- `([a-zA-Z0-9\.]*)` matches and captures CSS property value. Note that CSS property `color` has a wider value space than covered by this regex (e.g. `#fff`, `rgb(0,100,255)`, `rgba(...)`, `hsla(...)`), but this was not your question.

Comment: @beta: I've included some explanations. Have a nice coding :)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
/[\;\"\']{1}[\s]{0,1}color:[\s]{0,1}([a-zA-Z0-9\.]*)/ims
```

Comment: Hm it still seems to match background-color

Comment: Hm it includes the semicolon of the background-color as well but almost works as supposed. Any way to fix this one as well?

Comment: It would include the semicolon  of background-color, but the 2nd parameter of regex results that comes due to parenthesis () will only have the color code you want..

Comment: Oh ok I understand. The thing is I want to have everything in my result so that I can also remove the entire attribute from my style (by replacing it with empty string). This is why I was looking for a full match but only for the exact property I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for exact word match.  Try this

```
/^color: ([a-zA-Z0-9\.]*)$/
```

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't seem to work for me either. Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you try this `/\bcolor: ([a-zA-Z0-9\.]*)\b/`

Comment: Matches only the background-color :/